# Insert into when number of columns don't match number of values

Tags: mysql, insert

I have an insert sql statement, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO `table_a` (`col_a`, `col_b`, `col_c`, `col_d`) VALUES
(1, 2, 3, 4),
(2, 1, 6, 9),
(3, 1, 4, 5)
```

I want to insert this into another table, however the table I want to insert it into has a different structure to that of the sql statement (it has fewer fields) e.g.

```
table_b has columns 'col_a', 'col_b', 'col_d'
```

What do I have to do to the original sql statment so that I can get it to insert it into table_b.  I guess it would be something along the lines of just ignoring the value which is in col_c and just sending this to a temp variable rather than a field.e.g.

```
INSERT INTO `table_b` (`col_a`, `col_b`, @temp_var, `col_d`) VALUES
(1, 2, 3, 4),
(2, 1, 6, 9),
(3, 1, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Why exactly can't you just leave out the values you don't want to insert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTemp (
col_a integer,
col_b integer,
col_c integer,
col_d integer
);
INSERT INTO myTemp (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d) VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 1, 6, 9), (3, 1, 4, 5);
INSERT INTO table_a (SELECT col_a,col_b,col_d FROM myTemp);
```

The table gets dropped once your session ends (or you can remove it manually)

Comment: This is a really smart solution, I like it!

Answer (score 3):

How about you remove it?

```
INSERT INTO table_b (col_a, col_b, col_d) VALUES (1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 9), (3, 1, 5)
```

Comment: The insert into sql statement I have has over 100 rows to insert so don't want to go through and manually remove the rogue values.  I also don't have access to the original table so i cant remove it from the export either

Comment: @John: Could you write a script to modify the SQL and remove the values you don't want to insert?

Comment: I could but I just thought there might be an easy way where I could just change the column name to a variable name and mysql would then simply insert the value into this temp variable rather than the database.

If not I will just have to write something to handle this or manually input the data myself :(

Comment: I don't see why you don't want to do it manually, you should be done in less than 15 minutes.
Also, you don't need access to the table, you just need to modify the query wherever it is.

Comment: Use a regexp to change your SQL query:
(\([^,]*\), *\([^,]*\), *\([^,]*\), *\([^,]*\))
(\1, \2, \4)

Answer (score 2):

This is ugly, and I have just tried in in SQLite, but I can image that it also works in MySQL (the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) *doesn't* say it's *not* allowed) (**update**: see John's comment, it does *not* work in MySQL):

```
sqlite> create table t(a,b,c);
sqlite> insert into t (a,b,b,c) values (1,2,3,4);
sqlite> select * from t;
1|2|4
```

Comment: i'm not sure how that would work since you are inserting values into a column twice and if anything I would expect it to overrite the 2 with the 3.  Thanks for your help though and I will give it a try.

Comment: @John: Yes, it's weird. Would be interesting though if there's any documentation that actually defines the intended behavior of this query.

Comment: just tried it and it didn't work. Error returned was:

MySQL said:  

#1110 - Column 'type_id' specified twice

Comment: @John Okay, then it's SQLite specific.